# Connection refused with scrapy, privoxy and tor

Tags: curl, proxy, scrapy, tor

Privoxy, tor and scrapy 1.3.1 are installed and configured on my ubuntu 16.04 box. When I enter the following in a terminal I can see that privoxy/tor are working

```
export http_proxy="http://localhost:8118"
curl ipecho.net/plain; echo
```

I get a different IP from ipecho.net than mine.

When I run a test spider which does the same as the curl above and no proxy is enabled everything works well and I get a answer from ipecho.net.

When I add the proxy like

```
export http_proxy="http://localhost:8118"
scrapy crawl test
```

It results in an error message:

```
2017-02-14 07:45:36 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://ipecho.net/robots.txt> (failed 1 times): Connection was refused by other side: 111: Connection refused.
2017-02-14 07:45:36 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://ipecho.net/robots.txt> (failed 2 times): Connection was refused by other side: 111: Connection refused.
2017-02-14 07:45:36 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Gave up retrying <GET http://ipecho.net/robots.txt> (failed 3 times): Connection was refused by other side: 111: Connection refused.
2017-02-14 07:45:36 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt] ERROR: Error downloading <GET http://ipecho.net/robots.txt>: Connection was refused by other side: 111: Connection refused.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1297, in _inlineCallbacks
result = result.throwExceptionIntoGenerator(g)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/twisted/python/failure.py", line 389, in throwExceptionIntoGenerator
return g.throw(self.type, self.value, self.tb)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/middleware.py", line 43, in process_request
defer.returnValue((yield download_func(request=request,spider=spider)))
twisted.internet.error.ConnectionRefusedError: Connection was refused by other side: 111: Connection refused
```

Any idea what's going wrong with scrapy/twisted?

I also tried it with request.meta['proxy'] = "http://localhost:8118" or
a Proxy-Class.

Comment: Twisted 17 was released a few days ago, if you installed after that, you will have problems, revert it to Twisted 16.6 and you may be fine.

Comment: It is Twisted==16.6.0 installed. Any other idea?

Comment: I solved the problem. I updated from 16.6.0 to 17 and everything works well